# "Can't set data buffer before setting document buffer." for IVsTextLines

Tags: visual-studio-2019, mef, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, vspackage

In my VSIX project this error is shown on the line:

```cs
(AdapterService as IVsEditorAdaptersFactoryService).SetDataBuffer(textLines, projBuffer as IProjectionBuffer);
```

where `textLines` is created using `CreateInstance` method of my package

```cs
Type textLinesType = typeof(IVsTextLines);
Guid riid = textLinesType.GUID;
Guid clsid = typeof(VsTextBufferClass).GUID;
IVsTextLines textLines = (_package as Package).CreateInstance(ref clsid, ref riid, textLinesType) as IVsTextLines;
```

What actually is `DocumentTextBuffer` property and how do I set it on a newly instantiated `IVsTextLines`? 
What I am trying to do is create a `IVsTextLines` to pass it as a buffer to `IVsCodeWindow`.

Comment: Could you please [share a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with us to help us troubleshoot the issue? Besides, you can share the specific error with us.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT I think I've solved this by using `IVsEditorAdaptersFactoryService.CreateVsTextBufferAdapter`, and then calling `IVsTextBuffer.InitializeContent`. This initializes both the DocumentTextBuffer and DataTextBuffer, after which `IVsEditorAdaptersFactoryService.SetDataBuffer` throws no errors. I just need to make sure it `IVsCodeWindow.SetBuffer` is ok with it (probably is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the initialization of `textLines` to

```
textLines = AdapterService.CreateVsTextBufferAdapter(serviceProvider as IOleServiceProvider,
(contentTypeRegistry as IContentTypeRegistryService).GetContentType("csharp")) as IVsTextLines;
```

and then have used the [IVsTextBuffer.InitializeContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.textmanager.interop.ivstextbuffer.initializecontent?view=visualstudiosdk-2019) method to initialize the Document and Data text buffer to a single space character. After that I was able to successfully use the `SetBuffer` method.

I am still haven't finalized my extension, so I am not sure how relevant Document Buffer's content is.